# видеоплеер VLC сигнал окончания файла приходит два раза

Tags: c#, vlc

Пишу на C# VS 2017 плеер для воспроизведения видео с покадровой точностью. Требуемые форматы *.avi, *.mp4, *.mov. Для решения задачи использую видоплеер VLC VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows v3.0.18. Большинство поставленных задач плеер реализует, но в конце файла происходят странные вещи.

1. Сигнал окончания файла приходит два раза, причем как минимум один из сигналов не совпадает по вермени с заявленной длительностью файла (пробовала и vlcVideoView.MediaPlayer.Media.Duration, и vlcVideoView.MediaPlayer.Length - результаты совпадают).
2. Разница между двумя сигналами окончания файла составляет до сотни миллисекунд. Иногда первым отключается видео трек, а аудио продолжает вещать, пока я стою на точке останова между двумя сигналами окончания файла.
3. Думала, что два сигнала окончания файла связаны с тем, что в файле два трека, видео и аудио, но нет. Даже в тех файлах, где трек только один, сигнал окончания файла приходит дважды и не совпадает по времени с заявленным.
   Читала, что пользователи VLC плеера с этой проблемой сталкивались и решали её установкой плагинов более поздних версий (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/550?ysclid=lloutf9q8u919387009). А как это сделать в моём случае, если нужных пакетов NuGet найти не удалось?
   Буду благодарна за варианты решения проблемы с VLC плеером, а также за рекомендации относительно других видео плееров.

Comment: Вы не написали на какие события подписывались. Есть два события MediaPlayerEndReached и MediaPlayerStopped, может вам стоит подписаться на второе, т.к. первое вызывается при завершении обработки данных, но воспроизведение этих данных еще в процессе. Авторы указанной вами библиотеки рекомендуют использовать другое решение - https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp

Comment: Подписывалась на MediaStateChanged, как более универсальное. Попробую указанные Вами события, посмотрю, что получится.

Comment: Опробовала события MediaPlayerEndReached и MediaPlayerStopped. В них сигнал о конце файла приходит в то же время, что и в MediaStateChanged, и это время не соответствует заявленной длительности видеоролика. Не поняла, что за решение рекомендуют использовать авторы библиотеки. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: они предлагаю использовать другую библиотеку (ссылку я указал в своём первом комментарии)

Comment: Её я тоже использую. У меня одна без другой не заработала.